# Is the daedalus wallet seed phrase caps sensitive?

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, staking, daedalus, ada

I noticed my written down recovery phrase you can't really tell between caps and not caps and I have specifically drawn an arrow to "no caps" on a B on one sheet and some of the words that start with S or M are really hard to tell.

Should I send all my ADA back to Coinbase and make a new one just in case and make a notepad version so you can make a distinction between caps and non-caps but stick it on a USB as well as paper?

Also what situation would I need the recovery phrase? because I want to avoid the nerve-wracking of having to use it at all.

Im thinking of switching to YOROI instead maybe, or buy some more and store some in each wallet.

Many Thanks,

Jack.

Answer (score 2):

Cardano, Bitcoin, and many other protocols use the [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) standard for mnemonics. **It is not case sensitive, as it always defaults to lower case**.

Your recovery phrase is a secret you can use to derive/re-derive your wallet and its keys. You will need it anytime you wish to restore your wallet on any wallet software, like Daedalus, Yoroi, Nami, etc. It is essential to keep it safe and secure.

Generally speaking, a hardware wallet like [Ledger](https://www.ledger.com/) or [Trezor](https://trezor.io/) are your best bet if avoiding nerve-wrecking is what you're optimizing for.

On the other hand, if hardware wallets are not an option (whether you can't get your hands on them, or you're a power user with high customization requirements), then be very careful with what computer(s) you input your recovery phrase into. Airgapping is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got a reply on another forum earlier and for reference it's not cap sensitive and you can actually test it and get the green light in Daedalus settings. Recommendations say you do this every 6 months.
Mine went green so all good.

Here is the video someone linked me where you can check your seed phrase has been written down correctly by inputting it into daedalus any time you want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZEdSOs5Emw&feature=emb_title

Hope this helps future concerns for people's seed phrase being correct.